# how to splice different String with another String in xml in Android?

Tags: android, string, android-layout

I have some strings and I need to combine them in layout.xml, what is the best way?

Eg:

I have a simple login_layout.xml, it has many lines with a TextView as title and an `EditText` as input with a hint. Now I have four lines with input, I should define 8 Strings in `Strings.xml`. If I have more input lines in the future. For each additional input line, I need to define two strings.

Is there any way to make this simple?

For example, I only define one string for each input line, and for the hint, I can use such as: `android:hint="@string/please_enter + @string/account"` in the layout.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:text="@string/account" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/account"
            android:hint="@string/please_enter_account" />
        
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:text="@string/password" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:hint="@string/please_enter_password" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:text="@string/email" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:hint="@string/please_enter_email" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:text="@string/address" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:hint="@string/please_enter_address" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```xml
<string name="account">account</string>
<string name="password">password</string>
<string name="email">email</string>
<string name="address">address</string>
<string name="please_enter_account">please_enter_account</string>
<string name="please_enter_password">please_enter_password</string>
<string name="please_enter_email">please_enter_email</string>
<string name="please_enter_address">please_enter_address</string>
```

For this issue, I know I can define a **RecyclerView**, and use `getString(R.string.please_enter) + getString(R.string.account)`, but my project is more complicated, and that it can't use **RecyclerView** to implement it

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use string formatting like `String.format`.
create one string resources like this

```
<string name="please_enter">Please enter %s</string>
```

and a string for the text that is suppose to be appended (replaced with %s) like:

```
<string name="password">password</string>
```

in code u can use this:

```
getString(R.string.please_enter, getString(R.string.password))
```

the syntax of `getString` is like `String.format`. for more information check:
[here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings)

In case you want to use dataBinding you can use it as follows:

```
text="@{@string/please_enter(@string/password}"
```

Comment: Is there any other better way for layout.xml, if my project does not support dataBinding?

Comment: @Infinity_zhang not that i know of, either databing or through java code

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
String please_enter = getResources().getString(R.string.please_enter);
String account = getResources().getString(R.string.account);

EditText etaccount;
etaccount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.account);
etaccount.setHint(please_enter+" "+account);
```

Other than that you can do with [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#common_features) :

```
"@{@string/please_enter+ @string/account}"
```

Comment: Is there any other better way for layout.xml, if my project does not support dataBinding?

Comment: @Infinity_zhang i posted above method then you have to do it for every edittext.